# C++ _wcsicmp code is not compiling when comparing a ProcessEntry32.szExeFile, to user entered data

Tags: c++, process

So, I have this code:

```
using namespace std;
void targetProcessFinder(wchar_t targetProcess)
{

PROCESSENTRY32 entry;
entry.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);

HANDLE processSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, NULL);

if(Process32First(processSnapshot, &entry) == TRUE)
    {
        while(Process32Next(processSnapshot, &entry) == TRUE)
            {
                if (_wcsicmp(entry.szExeFile, targetProcess) == 0)
                {
                    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, entry.th32ProcessID);
                    int processID = entry.th32ProcessID;

                    CloseHandle(hProcess);
                }
            }
    }
}

int main()
{
    wchar_t targetProcess
    cin >> targetProcess;
    targetProcessFinder(targetProcess);
}
```

For some reason I am getting an error on the if(_wcsicmp...) line and I am completely lost as to why, I'ave tried changing the data types around to see if that is the issue but nothing seems to fix it.

Any advice?

Comment: `targetProcess` is a single `wchar_t`, it isn't a pointer to a sequence of `wchar_t`. So, yeah, the compiler is right to complain. It would help *significantly* if you understood (a) the function you're invoking and what it requires, and (b) that `cin >> targetProcess` was only saving a single character.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you elaborate on the error you're receiving? Please [edit] these details in so we can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

`void targetProcessFinder(wchar_t targetProcess)`

You're passing a single wchar_t, you need to pass a wchar_t*

`_wcsicmp(entry.szExeFile, targetProcess)`

If you're compiling with _MBCS compiler flag then PROCESS_ENTRY32.szExeFile is a regular char array, not a wchar_t array, in which case you need to switch your project's character set over to Unicode.